# MongoDB best practice setup

Tags: mongodb, docker

i am requiring a read-heavy failsave HA mongoDB host, wich will hold a few mio. documents on like 20 collections.

i got 2 physical servers. what is considered best practices to do a HA mongoDB setup with that less hardware?!

what i have found so far:

- ) Replica Set:
    Running with 2 nodes in a replica set, seems to be good but i am not sure, how this balances the reads (or the writes) - to scale: adding more replicas will work? (until 12?)
- ) Sharded Replica
    How to correctly do this with just 2 servers?
    (How to Scale?, adding a pair of servers (containers) - doing another replica set and adding it to the shardconfig?)

right now i used docker to run sharded-replica-cluster on 2 docker machines, each of them doing a replicaset, a few CFG servers, and a Router.

what are the downsides of using docker in that case to balance 2 hosts.

regards
helmut